# Visual Studio 2017 IWizard ProjectFinishedGenerating project is null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nullreferenceexception, envdte

I have the following code in my class that extends `IWizard`:

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
{
   MessageBox.Show(project.Name);
}
```

But it gives me the error:

`System.NullReferenceException HResult=0x80004003 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Saying that `project` is null. Which is right according to my debugger. However, what on earth causes this? I would've thought the method only gets called with a non-null project. How can I fix this?

Comment: Without knowing what you're aiming for, I would suggest just putting logic in to check for a null project and then handle that condition.

Comment: @RyanGibbs Already did that and it's only ever called with a null argument. This is driving me absolutely crazy as I've been on this for 3 days now.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is how that function is called. No one will be able to determine that based on the code you've provided.

Comment: @RyanGibbs No, because it's a function from the interface (IWizard). I don't call it myself at all. It should be called correctly.